# Disable Windows Effects when on Battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

Is there a program that will do the following things automatically when my laptop is on battery power?:

- Turn theme into Windows Classic
- Set battery option to "power saver"
- Disable all animations and effects
- Set a pause on any scheduled tasks

And I am on Windows 7. Also I want this to be reversed when my laptop is plugged in. :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AeroFoil](http://silentdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/aerofoil-150-released.html), it was made for exactly this :D